# RestEasy Interface and implementation

Tags: java, jboss, resteasy

All started to go fine without changing the code. That was problems in jboss configurations

I have interface like this

```
@Path("/send")
public interface Sender {

    @POST
    @Path("sms")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @FibianMethod(value = MethodAccess.ANY)
    FibResult sendBasketIdBySMS(@WebParam(name = "data") SendData data)
        throws FailureException;
}
```

I need to create an implementation of this interface.

```
@Stateless
@Named("sender")
public class SenderBean implements Sender {

    @Inject
    private MessageTemplateConnector manager;

    @Inject
    private BasketDao dao;

//    @Inject
//    private DbTemplateLookup templateLookup;

    @Inject
    private MessageBuilder messageBuilder;

    @Inject
    private RequestContext context;

    @Inject
    private BasketDao basketDao;

    @Override
    public FibResult sendBasketIdBySMS(SendData data) throws FailureException {
        PayBasket payBasket = dao.findBasket(data.getBasketId());
        if (payBasket.getStatus() != BasketStatus.PREPARED) {
            throw new FailureException(PayBasketError.UNKNOWN_BASKET);
        }

        Counts counts = basketDao.getCounts(payBasket, null, data.getPaySystemId());

        HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>(2);

        parameters.put("BASKET_CODE", data.getBasketId().toString());
        Double sum = counts.getTotalSumToPay() / 100d;

        parameters.put("SUM_TO_PAY", String.format("%8.2f", sum));

        InputMessage message = messageBuilder.getInputMessage("BASKET_NUMBER", context.getLangId(), parameters);
        message.setDestination(data.getPhoneNumber());
        message.setRecipient(data.getPhoneNumber());
        manager.sendMessage("SHIFTPAY", message);

        return new FibResult(Const.OK);
    }

}
```

When I deploy on JBOSS 7 I have an error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
    org.jboss.resteasy.util.GetRestful.getSubResourceClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)
```

All goes fine if implementation and mapping of rest interface is in one class.

Comment: Note that the implementation is annoated as both `@Stateless` and `@Stateful`; I believe this by itself should produce an error (though it shouldn't be the one you are getting).

Comment: And: are both the interface and implementation located in the same (WAR) project, or is the implementation in another (EJB perhaps) project?

Comment: In one ear. Now all goes fine without changing at all. I tried to fix that during two days. But when I post question on stack overflow all started to work. :)